# GradientLayer shows outside the button

Tags: swift, uibutton, cagradientlayer

I'm developing in Swift and want to make a rounded button with a gradient layer on it. At the corner of the buttons the gradient layer shows outside of the button. How to fix?

This is the code I made for it:

```
    let newLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    newLayer.frame = button.bounds
    newLayer.colors = [UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.lightGray.cgColor]
    button.layer.insertSublayer(newLayer, at: 0)

    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    button.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    button.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    button.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
    button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.init(width: 3, height: 3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add one more line:

```
button.clipsToBounds = true
```

And your result will be:

[image]